# Programs hang when writing to network share

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, network-share, file-sharing

i'm facing a weird problem when writing data to a network share from a Windows Server 2008 R2 computer.

When i write a file (saving a txt with notepad++, updating programs installed on the server remotely, when the system create thumbnails for pdfs, folders) the program writing the data hangs for ~5 seconds (sometimes up to 15 seconds !)

I wasn't able to find what causes this, and i faced the problem with 2 Windows 7 x64 clients (one Ultimate, on Pro).

If one of the Windows 7 client connect to an other Windows 7 clients on administrative shares, in testing purpose, i don't face any of theses hangs.

A little information on my setup :

-The clients all run on Windows 7 SP1 x64

-The server run Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

-None of the computer is part of a domain

-All the computer are in a homegroup

-All the computer uses a gigabyte realtek network controller (motherboard integrated)

-None of the computers have the same motherboard

-They are all connected with a CAT7 ethernet cable to a Netgear WNDR3700v2

-Net config SERVER state they are all visible, but the Win7Ultimate client

-Net config SERVER autodiconnect is set to -1 on the server and 10 mins on clients

-They all have the PowerShell v3 update

-Power strategy disallow hard drive sleep on server

-All "green" feature of realtek controllers are off

-Network type is set to home on all

-Password protected sharing is active

-All network controller was tested with motherboard's CD drivers, latest drivers from MSI and latest drivers from Realtek website.

-All computers uses Kaspersky Pure (desktop) Small office (Server) and had a test with Kaspersky fully unistalled

-All computers have a fixed MTU of 1472 with autotuning disabled

-To connect to the share, no password is prompted because accounts are "cloned" on all computers (account with the same name, password, rights created manually on each computer)

-Limited users have hangs on folders they have write rights too but don't have explorer hangs when exploring files when thumbnail generation is disabled. They hangs only when saving a file.

-Writing file on the share from the server itself (using RDP or a keyboard plugged to the server) works just fine.

-UAC is disabled on every computers

-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system\LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy is set to 1 on each computers

-Checked Auto Detect proxy settings in inetcpl > connections > LAN Settings

-Checked filesystem rights auditing, 0 fails appear on the logs and the succes is reccorded as soon as i hit ctrl+s in any program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem magically disappeared after installing a new network controller.

I don't have the problem on the Intel controller and don't have it anymore on the motherboard's built in.

I won't be able to explain the voodoo there, but it's solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking in the IE Options (inetcpl.cpl) if under Connections -> LAN Settings, Automatically Detect Proxy Settings is checked.  If it is, try unchecking it and see if that helps at all.  I saw an issue in the past where this setting caused a timeout scenario that resulted in hangs.  There are so many possibilities, this type of thing is best resolved by troubleshooting on your end.  You could try Wireshark to see which requests are taking longer, or enable filesystem auditing in the security log of the server to see if authorization negotiation is causing the lag.